# Safari 8.0.2 is adding www to certain domains - how can I disable this?

Tags: macos, safari, domain

When I type or paste a domain into the Safari URL bar that starts with http://local it always adds www.

I'm a web developer and have setup dozens of sites with the local. prefix but now can't test them in Safari.

Does anyone know how to disable this? (without changing my naming convention, of course)

Comment: I can’t give you a definite answer, but this is important: you need to be certain whether the WWW is being added by Safari, or by the server.  Many servers (unfortunately) forward to the WWW variant of URLs.